# I don't understand why this is printing empty lines every two loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
clout = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/j4Amhah6')
with open("MODULEADVANCED.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(clout.text.rstrip())
with open('MODULEADVANCED.txt', "r") as file:
    for eachLine in file:
        try:
            proxies = {
            'http': eachLine.rstrip(),
            'https': eachLine.rstrip()
            }       
            print(proxies['http'].rstrip())
        except:
           print("an error has occured")
```

This code is outputting the following:

```
127.0.0.1:0000

127.0.0.1:0000

127.0.0.1:0000

127.0.0.1:0000

127.0.0.1:0000

127.0.0.1:0000
```

Those empty spaces are just adding unjustified load to the system..
I tried sprinkling .rstrip()s everywhere but no dice...

Comment: Try another rstrip?

Comment: Can you please remove either of [python-3.x] pr [python-2.7] tags? Python2 and Python3 aren't really compatible. If you want to keep both, can you please state that it is compatible for both?

Comment: Removed one, my bad. Also another rstrip didn't work, don't know if that was supposed to be a joke lol

Comment: For debugging purposes why don't you try adding `repr` to see what is going on? I'm having trouble formatting this as I'd like in a comment, but here's an example: `a = "asdf\nasdf\nasdf"; print a
asdf
asdf
asdf
print repr(a)
'asdf\nasdf\nasdf'`

Comment: Downvote: I couldn't reproduce your code. Can you please add more stuff to your code so I can reproduce it directly, such as adding the Except in the Try?

Comment: Does that file have blank lines in it?

Comment: upon adding repr() this is what i obtain..:
    '127.0.0.1:0000'
    ''
- Edited code to finish with except so it can be easily reproduceable
-The file does not have blank lines in it..

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.

Comment: it would help if you added another `print` to the loop so we could tell if you're printing the blank on every other iteration, or they're part of the line that's being printed.

Comment: It's printing the blank on every other iteration, however for some reason there are unneccessary \n's on the file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem (Although not the proper way) would be:

```
print(proxies['http'].rstrip(), end='')
```

If this then prints everything on one line, then you propably save unnecessary `\n` to the file, so you should check the first part

```
with open("MODULEADVANCED.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(clout.text.strip())
```

maybe?

Comment: You are correct, I am somehow leaving unnecessary \n's in the file, investigating. Thank you for the lead